# Getting LayoutInflater using Context

Tags: android

Is there any difference between these two?

1. `inflater = (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater.from(context);`
2. `inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at the present time, as you can see by examining [the `LayoutInflater` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java). `from()` will throw an `Exception` rather than returning `null`, but otherwise they are identical.

Personally, I use `getLayoutInflater()` most times.